# Add simple products to configurable product using soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v1

I wants to associate simple products to configurable product from while creating the configurable product using soap api in magento1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catalog_product_link.assign SOAP V1 API method helps you achieve it.

Sample Code to associate products

```
$client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product_link.assign', array('configurable', $configurableProductSku, $associatedSimpleProductSku));
```

Go through this [magento article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductLink/catalog_product_link.assign.html) to get a grip on it.

**Edited:**

The association between a child and configurable products is different from the way it does with the rest of the product types ( like cross sell, up sell, grouped )in magento. Apparently, there is no direct SOAP method to provide such association. So, [this extension](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/) will achieve what you need.

Comment: Hi @nikin i tried the above code, iam getting Error: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [100] Given invalid link type.

Comment: Try replacing `configurable ` type with `grouped` type and check it. `$client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product_link.assign', array('grouped', $configurableProductSku, $associatedSimpleProductSku));`

Comment: But , i wants to assign simple products to configurable products

Comment: No, just want to make sure that the system does not throw any exception when replaced with `grouped` type. Anyway, looks like the association between simple and configurable products is different from the way it does with the rest of the product types ( like cross sell, up sell, grouped ) in magento. Apparently, there is no direct SOAP method to provide such association. So, could you use this [extension](http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/) and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, i installed that extension, but products are assigning to config while creating simple at the same time while creating the config only.

Answer (score 0):

This extension is worked for me :

http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/04/20/magento-api-associate-simple-products-to-configurable-or-grouped-product/

Thanks

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I have edited my answer to include this solution. Could you please **accept** my answer.

Comment: Hi @nikin i am able to associate simple product to cofigurable while creating the product only, but iam unable to associating existing simple products to configurable product, if you have any idea please let me know